# PostScript string conversion failed - can't catch /typecheck error

Tags: postscript

I want to check the type of the top most parameter in my function and convert it to int if it's type is string. If the string contains letters I get a /typecheck error. My code is:

```
/doConvert {
    dup type /stringtype eq { cvi } if
...
} def
```

Now I can save the value in a variable and do something like this:

```
/a exch def a type /stringtype eq { {a cvi} stopped {pop 0} if} if
```

Can I get the same result without using variables? I have tried using **cvx** and **exec** but I always get the /typecheck error because I do not have the type conversion in curly brackets.

Comment: You never need to use 'variables' in PostScript (which doesn't really have a concept of variables as such, what you are doing there is defining a key/value pai in a dictionary, which you can treat as a kind of variable). You can simply leave the operand on the stack and have the procedure consume an operand from the stack. Something like "dup type /stringtype eq {{cvi} stopped {pop 0} if}{pop}ifelse"

Comment: It works. Thank you! I tried to get the string into the curly brackets as well. Why can I write only the operator in curly brackets. In the documentation it looks like the whole expression (the string (aa) and the operator cvi) has to be in parentheses.

Comment: In your example `{ cvi }` is an executable array and stopped executes it. Thanks!